# reading a resource using GetManifestResourceStream

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a binary file from a resource using

```
Stream input = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
```

where resourceName is a string, containing the resource's filename. I'm getting a null object back.
I tried the fully qualified path (e.g. "myAssemblyName.Properties.Resources." + resourceName) but that didn't work either.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Check out [How to embed and access resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) and see if it helps to solve your problem. If not - you'll be able to add more details in the question.

Comment: Make sure that for the resource name you use "NameOfNameSpace.Resources.NameOfFileInTheResource" . Also, Could you be using `Properties.Resources.yourresource` ?

Comment: Guessing the name right can be difficult, a big reason why Visual Studio has a resource designer.  Run ildasm.exe on your assembly, double-click the manifest and pay attention to the `.mresource` statements.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips and help.
First, for some reason the resource manager doesn't let me embed the file - Persistence is set on "Linked at compile time" and I cannot change it, it is ghosted.
But also - I made a small test app with a single bitmap resource, where I input a string and it tries to open a resource stream from this string. I used ILDASM and found the namespace and name, but it fails again!
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your file is included in the project.
Make sure that the "Build Action" for your file is set to "Embedded Resource".
Check what the name is with

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
```

Load the resource stream with

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream()
```